# What should I use to get rid of some kind of weed in my onions

Tags: vegetables

I bought Lentagran herbicide but in its package is written that it is used against three other weeds but not the one I am having problems with. It says that Lentagran WP can be used to control weeds like: black nightshade, cleavers and fat hen. I will post a photo of my onions (you can barely see them from the weed). Is it possible that the herbicide I bought works on these kind of weed too and if not what should i use?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me, it seems a easy job (and quicker) to do it by hand: not many and large plants. Not many small and new one, so it seems there are not many seeds around.

Do you know what plant it is? Where do the seeds come? (to me it seems artichokes).

Other trick (on so nice garden): dig twice, with some week space between the first and the second one. Most plants will grow and will be killed on second dig. This is a trick on organic cultures (specially if you do it mechanically).

Or you can look standard herbicides. Your weed is dicotyledon (like weed on lawn), and onion are monocotyledons (like grass in lawn), so a very common case, and with a lot of herbicides. Just that they seems artichokes, so  leathery leaves, so more difficult with herbicides.

Answer (score 8):

When the weeds are this size it is best to weed them by hand. 
Then after a week or two turn the top layer of the earth to kill off weed seedlings.
To cover the earth with mulch also helps.

Answer (score 6):

Agree with other answers that it's best to weed by hand. Apart from questions as to whether a herbicide will work, why add a herbicide to something you're going to eat if you have a choice not to? They are generally safe if used correctly but less is still better (for health and environment).

If you have a large area to weed, using a hoe will help to speed up the job - and can be used standing up which is kinder on the knees/back.

However, try to work out what it is before you start weeding - if it's not actually a weed you might want to re-think digging it up! I'd certainly be pleased to have an established patch of artichokes in my garden...